# What is a good search engine for embedding in a web site

Tags: asp.net, search-engine

I am thinking of changing my web site's homegrown search engine. Before I break out Visual Studio, I wondered if anyone can suggest an alternative that gives me what I need. This being:

- Works with an ASP.NET site (is a .NET project)
- Creates a file-based index
- Fast search across hundreds or thousands of pages
- Performs word-stemming to find variations upon words
- Gives full control over the output styles
- Is cheap (or better still, free!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [.NET version of Lucene](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) is what we've been using.  It meets all of your criteria.

Comment: Do you have an example site I can take a gander at?

Comment: http://www.EstateSales.NET  The search at the top right is using it.  Search for Memphis or something like your city name.

Answer (score 6):

You can't really beat [Google Site Search](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/) for this.  It's fully customizable - and no need for embedding or maintaining.

EDIT: found this [ASP.NET opensource search engine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Searcharoo_4.aspx) that you can take and run with, In response to your comment about knowing what google does, this is [well documented and they have TONS of webmaster tools for you](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dashboard?pli=1).

Comment: Google site search  keeps the indexed data on it own servers, right ? So this way the server load is also reduced at our end? & considering a big website like stackoverflow which is frequently updated with newer data, wont frequent indexing by google cause an overload on our database servers due to too many database queries to return pages to google, as it attempts to index the newer data ?

Comment: Google Site Search has been discontinued as of 02/21/2017

Answer (score 4):

First I would agree with Google Site Search.

However, if you want to search on criteria that Google might not see (like stuff in the database, etc), then you might look at **[Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)**.  It is a port of the Java Lucene project:

> Apache Lucene is a high-performance, full-featured text search engine library written entirely in <strike>Java</strike> .Net. It is a technology suitable for nearly any application that requires full-text search, especially cross-platform.

It is free under the Apache license.

Comment: Google site search keeps the indexed data on it own servers, right ? So this way the server load is also reduced at our end? & considering a big website like stackoverflow which is frequently updated with newer data, wont frequent indexing by google cause an overload on our database servers due to too many database queries to return pages to google, as it attempts to index the newer data ?

Comment: could you please respond to my above doubt ? Thanks for your time !!

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you try out [google custom search engine](http://www.google.com/coop/cse/)? If you want ultimate control over the indexing you can create your own search engine using [lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)

Comment: I tried it but it does not seem to give me the control I am after. Particularly it doesn't allow me to show the icons that I currently show alongside results. I am also concerned that it indexes when Google wants, not necessarily when I want it to.

Answer (score 2):

From [my question "In-house full-text search engine for source code and SQL scripts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90300/in-house-full-text-search-engine-for-source-code-and-sql-scripts):

> I use [Hyper Estraier](http://hyperestraier.sourceforge.net/), but
>   [Namazu](http://www.namazu.org/index.html.en) is also well-known.

There are also [ht://Dig](http://www.htdig.org/), [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/), [Xapian](http://xapian.org/), etc.. but I don't know too much about them.

Answer (score 2):

DTSearch engine at http://www.dtsearch.com/ is a solid engine that is easy to develop against. Although it does cost money.

Comment: Pretty lame that testing/dev servers require separate licenses: http://www.dtsearch.com/dtStore.html