# How to make a search engine for my apps

Tags: asp.net, sql, search-engine

**Duplicate of:**

> [What is a good search engine for embedding in a web site.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146388/what-is-a-good-search-engine-for-embedding-in-a-web-site)

I mainly build apps in asp.net using a ms sql backend. Does anyone have a dummy guide for making a good search engine? I've been told not to you like statements in my stored procedures. If I don't use like, how do I search for terms with in all my columns containing text?

Comment: Will lucene allow me to run a search and display the results in a gridview control?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the best way of making a good search engine is ... not doing it.

Use [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) or any other out-of-the-box search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make one. Look at [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) or similar search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for "let someone else do your work".

You could give [Google custom search](http://www.google.com/coop/cse/) a try. Has worked well when I've used it and you might make some money off the advertising.